# android app not working in ver. 2.3

Tags: android

My app works fine on android version 4.0+, but there is an error when i try to start it on ver. 2.3
any suggestions?
android:minSdkVersion="8" 
android:targetSdkVersion="15"

> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.Catholic_app/com.example.Catholic_app.News.Top}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class fragment
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307): Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class fragment
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.setMenu(SlidingMenu.java:375)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   com.example.Catholic_app.News.Top.createSlidingMenu(Top.java:81)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   com.example.Catholic_app.News.Top.onCreate(Top.java:70)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   ... 11 more
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.Catholic_app-1.apk]
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
>
> 09-16 21:37:29.759: E/AndroidRuntime(8307):   ... 19 more

I do not use getSupportFragmentManager() or getFragmentManager() methods in my code. 
I use addition lib "sliding menu". 
Erorr ocured in this code

```
slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);
```

where i call next method of slidingmenu library

```
public void setMenu(int res) {
    setMenu(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(res, null));
}
```

My **R.layout.slidingmenu** file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <fragment   
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:name="com.example.Catholic_app.Menu.SlidingMenuFragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/slidingmenu"> </fragment>
```

P.s. support-library-v4 has been already added

Comment: Please use the android support fragment library.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258160/how-to-use-android-support-library-correctly

Comment: Please Post your layout file code.

Answer (score 2):

To use the `Fragment` below the version 3.0 you have to use its Support library in your application.

You should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();`

For more details check [HERE](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/)

**To add one of the libraries to your Android project:**

```
In your Android project, create a directory named libs at the root of your project (next to src/, res/, etc.)
Locate the JAR file for the library you want to use and copy it into the libs/ directory.

For example, the library that supports API level 4 and up is located at <sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar.
Add the JAR to your project build path.
```

Comment: i do not use getSupportFragmentManager() or getFragmentManager() methods in my code. I use addition lib "sliding menu". Erorr ocured in this code in library setMenu(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(res, null));
when i call method in my activity onCreate         slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);  P.s. support-library-v4 has been already added

Comment: My R.layout.slidingmenu file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:name="com.example.Catholic_app.Menu.SlidingMenuFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/slidingmenu">
</fragment>

Answer (score 0):

when you create an android app you set the `minimum sdk version` , `target sdk` and `compile with`check it like that pictute!

[image: 1]

Comment: he/she set android:minSdkVersion="8" (Android 2.2 Froyo) - this is already sufficient for his/her need to run the app under Android 2.3